# Would image hosting site need 1gbps or 100mbps port

Tags: performance, hosting, port, image

Hello guys, 
            i just need some advice.I want to start my own image hosting.However i am confused whether it would require 100mbps port speed or 1gbps.Files uploaded by users will be 15mb in size.I expect around 1000+ image uploads/day at peak.

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100mbps port speed will be sufficient for any site starting out.  If you have 15mb files uploaded 1000 times, that's 15,000 mb per day.  Considering there are 86,400 seconds per day, you'll average well less than 1 mbps for uploads.  But I'd guess the real usage would be from downloads / views?  I think you'll be fine, you can always up it later and that's "a good problem to have".

Comment: Thanks for the response .... considering views i think that one image may reach around 100 000+ per day as if popular sites use my host, i will get many views.All i want to avoid is slow loading of images and ensure best user experience.

Comment: i'd definitely set up bandwidth monitoring of some sort and be ready to move to a CDN when your traffic justifies it.